# Python Jenkins API does not allow to queue several jobs at once. Is there a way to work around the restriction?

Tags: python, jenkins

There is a parametrized job in my Jenkins server. I would like to initiate several builds of the job with different parameters using Python Jenkins API. This is completely legitimate in Jenkins. If I call 'invoke' method of the same job instance several times, the API starts only the first build and rejects to queue another builds because it considers that the job is already in the queue.

I am using Python Jenkins API version 0.2.14. This is the latest version of the API on the current moment.
I have taken a look into the Jenkins API source code and it really restricts to invoke a new build until there is another job in the queue (job.py: lines 104,105):

```
if self.is_queued():
    raise WillNotBuild('%s is already queued' % repr(self))
```

Is there a way to get over the restriction? I have found some way (see the sample below), but I am not sure it is the best way to do it. Maybe there are different solutions. I would like to know about these solutions if there are ones.

In my solution I have created a subclass `ParameterizedJob` of the original `jenkinsapi.job.Job` class and I have overridden four methods: `__init__`, `invoke`, `is_queued`, `is_queued_or_running`. I have instantiated a job object from my class instead of calling get_job method from the Jenkins instance. This approach works fine for me.

```
import jenkinsapi
from jenkinsapi.job import Job

class ParametrizedJob(Job):
    def __init__(self, jobname, jenkins_instance):
        self._allowQueuingMultipleBuilds = False
        jobExists = False
        for info in jenkins_instance._data["jobs"]:
            if info["name"] == jobname:
                Job.__init__(self, info["url"], info["name"], jenkins_obj=jenkins_instance)
                jobExists = True
                break
        if not jobExists:
            raise UnknownJob(jobname)

    def invoke(self, securitytoken=None, block=False, skip_if_running=False, invoke_pre_check_delay=3, invoke_block_delay=15, build_params=None, cause=None):
        self._allowQueuingMultipleBuilds = True
        try:
            Job.invoke(self, securitytoken, block, skip_if_running, invoke_pre_check_delay, invoke_block_delay, build_params, cause)
        except:
            raise
        finally:
            self._allowQueuingMultipleBuilds = False

    def is_queued_or_running(self):
        if not self._allowQueuingMultipleBuilds:
            return Job.is_queued_or_running(self)
        else:
            return False

    def is_queued(self):
        if not self._allowQueuingMultipleBuilds:
            return Job.is_queued(self)
        else:
            return False

def startJenkinsJob(jenkinsInstance, jobName, parameters):
    #targetJob = jenkinsInstance.get_job(jobName)
    targetJob = ParametrizedJob(jobName, jenkinsInstance)
    targetJob.invoke(securitytoken='TOKEN', build_params=parameters, block=True)
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not schedule the same job several times through the UI either. Exception is, if you have a parametrized job, and both starts have different parameters.

Comment: I do not think it is true. I have just tried to run several builds of the same job with the same parameters and Jenkins started all of them simultaneously and the same slave. So, you can try it yourself. It should work fine. I am pretty sure that it is true for non-parametrized jobs as well.